# iTunes music on NAS, library file local - always losing the music folder in preferences

Tags: itunes, buffalo-nas

I have a Buffalo Linkstation which I point to in my iTunes preferences as my library. Problem is, if my computer sleeps for a while, it loses the connection with the NAS and I have to reset the iTunes music folder and wait for it to Update the library. Should I create a local symlink or something? 
I tried the Linkstation's iTunes server functionality but can't seem to create playlists with it for the life of me so this way seems to be better.